# How do I increase the size of the login boxes and move them into the middle of the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to coding and have been trying to create a fairly basic login window using Tkinter. So far it works as intended but I'm trying to make it look more appealing.

```
class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        master.title("SEN Tracker Login")
        master.geometry("500x320")

        self.grid()
        self.labelLogin = Label(self, text = "Login")
        self.labelLogin.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=2)

        self.label_Username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_Password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_User = Entry(self)
        self.entry_Pass = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_Username.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
        self.label_Password.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
        self.entry_User.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=3)
        self.entry_Pass.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=3)
```

This is the code I have created so far, it does not include the part which compares the text entered for the login. Using this creates a window as follows:

[image: Login window]

I was hoping to get some help moving the top left widgets to the center and enlarging them, I don't mind how big, I just want to know how to do it really.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tkinter, probably should of added that part

Comment: Yes, you should have.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for the specific question you're having.

Comment: There's nothing special about Login box as far as layout is concerned. Your question is essentially: _"How to resize and center a widget?"_ Which includes separate questions that each are answered at least tens of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **pack** geometry manager

For you to center you your widget in the middle of the `window` use `pack` which will center it and also you have to use `width` method to increase the size of the `entry` widget

```
class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        master.title("SEN Tracker Login")
        master.geometry("500x320")

        self.grid()
        self.labelLogin = Label(self, text = "Login")
        self.labelLogin.pack()

        self.label_Username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_Password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_User = Entry(self, width=20)
        self.entry_Pass = Entry(self, show="*", width=20)

        self.label_Username.pack()
        self.label_Password.pack()
        self.entry_User.pack()
        self.entry_Pass.pack()
```

Using **place** geometry manager

You can use place geometry manager to position your widget where you prefer `place` gives you flexibility as you can increase the `x` and `y` figure you want to position the widget.

```
class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        master.title("SEN Tracker Login")
        master.geometry("500x320")

        self.grid()
        self.labelLogin = Label(self, text = "Login")
        self.labelLogin.place(x=250, y=150)
        self.label_Username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_Password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_User = Entry(self)
        self.entry_Pass = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_Username.place(x=250, y=170)

        self.label_Password.place(x=250, y=190)

        self.entry_User.place(x=250, y=220)

        self.entry_Pass.place(x=250, y=240)
```